# How I can get Hangouts notifications on my phone even if I have it open in my PC

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts, google-voice, sms

**EDIT: Google Hangouts is dead, so this question no longer has any relevance. Probably not worth any further discussion**

I have a Google Voice number, and can send and receive SMS messages using both the website (through [gmail.com](https://gmail.com)) or from the Hangouts app on my Galaxy S3.

If I have an open desktop web browser on Gmail, and receive an SMS message, my browser pops up the message and gives me a notification, but nothing happens on my phone (I can open Hangouts and see the message - I just don't get any notification). This happens even if my web browser doesn't even have the Gmail tab active, just if it's open in the background.

If my web browser is closed, then the notification happens on my phone.

I'm assuming Hangouts thinks that since the message came through on my browser, that I don't need to be notified on the phone.

I don't see any setting on Gmail, Google Voice website, or in the Android app for disabling this - anyone have any ideas on how I can get notifications on my phone even if I have a browser open?

Comment: What if you don't have the chat box open, but have it minimized in Gmail, is it still an issue then?

Comment: It's weird - the more I test it, the more inconsistent it gets. Seems like the messages go to the phone even if GMail is open, but if I acknowledge and close/minimize the chat from there, future messages in that conversation don't go through to the phone. If I F5 the browser, seems like only the very first message goes to the phone notification - which is good enough but still weird. And then I tried closing the GMail browser tab completely and it still only notified my phone about half the time.

Comment: I am getting a new phone in a week, so I wonder if that will make any kind of difference - this is an S3, getting an S6 next week.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. Sounds really weird. Have you tried a different browser? Google Chrome?

Comment: The only browser I've used on the desktop is Chrome.

Comment: Following up to my own question - not a solution, but there is an option in Hangouts to send an email for every incoming SMS, and those emails do trigger notifications on my phone through the mail app - so even though I don't get a nice SMS beep on my phone, I'll still get notified that there's an incoming message.

Comment: Hangouts web application no longer exists.